# make: *** No targets. Stop while building linux kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, make

I am just trying to learn how to driver modules for Linux Kernel. I followed Linux Device drivers 3rd edition book and started my work. I created a sample program and makefile. Please find my makefile contents below.

```
obj-m += testModule.o
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.36/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

I saved this makefile in my home directory. Whenever I am trying to execute this file using

```
make
```

command I am getting

```
make: *** No targets.  Stop
```

error. Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, that two-line block is your Makefile?  Try putting a line that says `all:` or `my_program:` or `foo:` (the **`:`** is critical) immediately before the line that says `make -C /lib/modules/3.2.36/build M=$(PWD) modules`, and make sure that _that_ line (the `make -C ...` line) is indented by a tab.

Comment: I tried! It worked!! Thank you so much Scott. Since it is my first linux dirver, I did silly mistakes. I apologize. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: There is another problem in the makefile. The make inside the  makefile is going on recursion it is not picking my linux source tree makefile.

Comment: This question should belong on stack overflow

Comment: @Rengasami: D’oh!  I missed that.  Recursion in `Makefile`s is not _necessarily_ bad, but you’re probably better off avoiding it.  //  @Benji: I disagree.  It _could_ have been asked on Stack Overflow or Super User, but it’s in scope for Unix and Linux.

Answer (score 3):

That `make -C` command should be separated,

i.e

```
obj-m += testModule.o

default:
    make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```